# Prove or disprove that n³=theta(n²)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I found the following problem in my professor's slides with no solution:

> Prove or disprove that *n<sup>3</sup> = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*

So I made an attempt to solve it myself. But I don't know if my solution is correct or not, I feel like it is though:

We need to find a *c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>*, and *n<sub>0</sub>* such that:

*c<sub>1</sub>⋅g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>⋅g(n)*

I found that:

*c<sub>1</sub>⋅n<sup>2</sup> ≤ n<sup>3</sup> ≤ c<sub>2</sub>⋅n<sup>2</sup>*

and:

*c<sub>1</sub> = 1, c<sub>2</sub> = 1, n<sub>0</sub> = 1*

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that `f(n) = Theta(g(n))` is equivalent to saying that `f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = Omega(g(n))`.
While it is correct (and trivial to prove) that `n^3 = Omega(n^2)` it does not hold that `n^3 = O(n^2)`.
Proof:
Let `c` be a constant, we need to show that for all `n0`, there exists `n > n0` s.t. `f(n) > cg(n)` => `n^3 > cn^2`.
Fix `n0`, and by choosing `n = max(c, n0 + 1) > n0`, we get that `n^3 = n*n^2 > c*n^2`, completing the proof.

Comment: So it is not true? I found a c_1 and c_2 with n_0 = 1. For example, c_1 * n^2 < n^3 I found c_1 = 1 with n_0 = 1

Comment: No, it's not true, What you showed is the `n^3 = Omega(n^2)` and this is correct (as I mentioned in my answer), but the second condition does not hold.

Comment: Oh ok so upper bound: n^3 < c_2 * n^2, n_0=1 c_2 = 1... So at this point I have found both sides of the inequalities to hold true?

Comment: Exactly, you also need to show `n^3 < c_2 * n^2` (for all `n > n0`) and I demostrated how to refute it.

Comment: Oh for all n > n_0, ohhhh WHICH I can't because if c_1 equals 1, n_0 = 1, the moment n becomes 2, all of a sudden it does not work

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is wrong,

```
C1 n² < n³ < C2 n²
```

can be simplified as

```
C1 < n < C2
```

which cannot hold, as `n` is unbounded (so there is no such `C2`).